# Reading information from a map embedded in a website

Tags: android, google-maps

My university bus system has a live-view of the current location of the buses on its website (uses Google Maps) and I want to be able to get that information from the site so that I can display it on a mobile app (on the Android platform, specifically). Is there any way to do this and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do that. You will need to learn about Map Overlays.

See : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html

Comment: that's for displaying the map on Android though isn't it? I can figure that out, but I don't know how to get the information I need for the overlay from a site. Let me know if I misunderstood

Comment: That's correct. My bad. The best way to get your University's overlay would be to speak to the developers of that application.